# Parameters for existence of Solutions for Inhomogeneous BVP Equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been studying the Fredholm Alternative recently and have become stuck on a couple of questions.

What values of $A$ and $B$ will give a solution for the following BVPs?

[image]

I know that $Q_1$ is self adjoint, and the adjoint for $Q_2$ for $w_0$ is $e^x$.

How do I solve this and

How do I tackle $Q_2$?

Thank you for your help!

Any other examples on the web for questions like this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The operator in part (a)** is selfadjoint in $L^2[0,2\pi]$ on the domain satisfying the homogeneous endpoint conditions. The homogeneous equation has non-trivial solutions $C\cos x + D\sin x$. Therefore, the inhomogeneous equation has a solution iff the right side is orthogonal to $\cos x$ and $\sin x$. You can write those conditions
$$
    \int_{0}^{2\pi}(A\sin x + B\cos x+2\sin(x+\pi/3)+\sin^3 x)\cos x dx = 0,\\
    \int_{0}^{2\pi}(A\sin x + B\cos x+2\sin(x+\pi/3)+\sin^3 x)\sin x dx = 0.
$$
The first condition does not involve $A$ because $\sin x$, $\cos x$ are orthogonal, while the second equation does not involve $B$. You can use the trig identity $\sin(x+\pi/3)=\sin(x)\cos(\pi/3)+\cos(x)\sin(\pi/3)$ to simplify the second term.

**The operator in part (b)** can be put into selfadjoint form on the weighted space $L^2_{e^{2x}}[0,1]$:
$$
          Lf=\frac{1}{e^{2x}}\left[\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{2x}\frac{df}{dx}\right)+e^{2x}f\right]=f''+2f'+f
$$
You can solve the homogeneous equation $Lf=0$ subject to the conditions
$$
                      f(0)+f'(0)=A \\
                      f(1)+f'(1)=3.
$$
The solution is $f_0(x)=Ce^{x}+Dxe^{x}$ where
\begin{align}
      A & =f_0(0)+f_0'(0) = C+(C+D) = 2C+D \\
      3 & =f_0(1)+f_0'(1) = (C+D)+(C+2D)=2C+3D
\end{align}
So the original problem reduces to finding a solution $y=f-f_0$ of
$$
           y''+2y'+y=1 \\
           y(0)+y'(0)=0 \\
           y(1)+y'(1)=0.
$$
There is a non-trivial solution of the homogeneous equation for $y$; that solution is $e^{-x}$. So the inhomogeneous equation has a solution iff $(e^{-x},1)_{e^{2x}}=0$, which does not hold:
$$
    (e^{-x},1)_{e^{2x}} = \int_{0}^{1}(e^{-x})(1)e^{2x}dx = e^{x}|_{0}^{1}=e-1.
$$

Comment: For part a why do you consider cos x and sin x separately?

Comment: Why not consider the inner product with (cosx + sinx) directly? Thank you!

Comment: @J.Bant : The null space of the operator with periodic conditions is two-dimensional and spanned by $\{\cos x,\sin x\}$. So is the deficiency. There are two equations, then: one obtained by an inner product with $\cos$ and the other with $\sin$. One isolates $A$ and the other isolates $B$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there any way of using Fredholm's Alternative to simplify this. I know that <f, wo> must = 0 for a non-unique solution to exist. Is there anything else I need to add to justify this?

Comment: @J.Bant : I'm basically using the Fredholm Theorem, but in the special case of selfadjoint operators, where $\mathcal{N}(L)=\mathcal{R}(L)^{\perp}$. In this case, the null space is the orthogonal complement of the range, which gives Fredholm index 0. Somehow you have to figure out the deficiency space in order to know if you can solve your equation on not; it's the orthogonal complement of the null space.